# How to always show the header side bar in Leanback BrowseFragment?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

In Android TV `leanback`, how to always show the headers which are to the left of the screen in `BrowseFragment` even when an item in any row is selected?

Currently when an item in a row is focused on, the side bar containing the headers is hidden. I want the side bar to always be shown.

[image: Sample of side bar]

The side bar in blue in the above picture will always be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Please override the following method into RowFragment and set true in setExpand method. Hopefully, it will be worked

```
 @Override
    public void setExpand(boolean expand) {
        super.setExpand(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override `startHeadersTransition`. Just `return` inside this method to prevent any headers transition.